# Logged in Username in Sharepoint 2010 Forms Based Authentication

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, sharepoint-2010, forms-authentication

When using forms based authentication in Sharepoint 2010, suppose user is logged in with username "admin" and our custom membership provider name is "FBAProvider"... After logging in with this account, logged in user name is displayed like "i:0#.|FBAProvider|admin". How can make it display as it should be like just "admin"?

Thanks in advance,

Mete

Answer (score 1):

What code are you using to display the username?

```
SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser
```

will give you a [SPUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.aspx) object. There are many properties that you can use there, and assuming that your User Information List has the correct information (which it must if you user logs in using only "admin" and not "FBAProvider::admin". Find the field that has the display information that you are looking for.

I'm guessing either [Email](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.email.aspx), [LoginName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.loginname.aspx) or [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.name.aspx)

Comment: Well it does not come from any custom code or control. It comes from Sharepoint's welcome.ascx that displays personal actions menu. If there is no out of the box solutions, it seems i will have to develop a custom usercontrol to do the same job....

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and found that it seemed to have something to do with rights to the database.  The application pool for the site was running as NetworkSystem -- when I changed it to LocalSystem, the username was displayed.

I'd suggest making sure the identity of your application pool has rights to the ASP database.